# What's a good tag for poop?

Tags: discussion, tags

We've got these tags:

- [diaper](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diaper)
- [potty-training](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/potty-training)
- and even [encopresis](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/encopresis)

But we *don't* have anything for bowel movements or urination, which was a bit of a surprise to me since new parents of newborns and infants tend to worry about frequency, consistency, and/or color of stool.

What would a good tag be?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest [urine](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/urine) and [stools](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stools).

I feel that urine is a go-to synonym for pee in polite company.

Likewise with stools. Some people use bowel movements (or BMs), but I find this too wordy. Feces also seems too technical for a basic bodily... output to be used as a tag.

No reason not to use synonyms and point them to the tags I mentioned.

Comment: Good point about synonyms!